# Orthotic inserts + athletes foot

Tags: fungal-infection, orthotics, podiatry, athletes-foot, footwear

With athletes foot, it's important to keep the feet dry.  However, when wearing sandals, I can't use the "super feet" orthotic inserts that keep my feet from developing pain issues when I walk.

I think this is a temporary need, so I would rather not buy special footwear just for this.  At work, I need to at least slip off my shoes while at my desk, but putting my shoes back on whenever I need to stand up for a meeting to to chat with a coworker seems silly.

Sandals just aren't cutting it, though.  I have nice, gel-footed sandals, but I am still getting some pain issues in my feet because I am not using the best inserts I know about.

Any suggestions?  For example, is there a way to tie my shoes that would make them super easy to slip on and yet still provide enough support?

One idea I am considering is keeping an alternate pair of shoes at my desk which are tied extremely loosely and slipping them on when I need shoes--but I still feel a bit awkward about it all.

Any other ideas or suggestions?

Tags I can't create/add: podiatry, shoes, othotics, fungal-infections, etc...